# Do you have to check for null & length or is there a shorter way to verify a non-empty string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, string

I set the value of a hidden field `#thimble` on page load using server-side values.

Then in JavaScript I want to act on that value only if it has been populated with some non-empty string.

Is this the most concise way of checking that the value is non-empty?

```
if ($("#thimble").val() != null && $("#thimble").val().length > 0) {
    carryOn();
}
```

Seems rather long.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An empty string is a *falsey* value, I wouldn't even bother to check its `length`.

The following is equivalent to your example:

```
if ($("#thimble").val()) {
    carryOn();
}
```

A *falsey* value is a value that produces `false` when evaluated in Boolean context (such as the condition of an `if` statement).

Falsey values are:

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`
- `0`
- `""` (empty string)
- `false`

Remember that a string in *Boolean* context produces `false` only when its length is `0`, if it has whitespace it still produce `true`:

```
Boolean("");     // false
Boolean("    "); // true, whitespace
```

Comment: `if it has whitespace it still produce true`: Wouldn't it be better to trim it first, in that case?

Comment: @Billy G. Sure, you can use `$.trim()`.

Comment: @Billy, Yep, as @alex said use `$.trim`, I just reproduced your example... `$("#thimble").val().length > 0` will still produce `true` with a string containing only whitespace... trim first :)

Answer (score 3):

If by non-empty, you mean *anything other than zero-length or whitespace-only* , then use [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) with `.length`:

```
if ($.trim($("#thimble").val()).length) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: ...and as @CMS points out in his insightful answer, the `length` call is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, CMS's answer is a very good explanation but I wonder why he doesn't include `trim` as you do here - even if `length` is unnecessary.

Comment: I think he was adding value to the discussion. He realized that trimming the value had already been mentioned and opted to not duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#thimble").val().length) {
    carryOn();
}
```